# Form authentication except for one page

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, web-config

Hi I'm creating a small site with MVC, I've got about three pages, I'm trying to allow access for all users on a certain page. The page is created in my "HomeController index".

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name="Test" timeout="10080">
    </forms>
   </authentication>
</system.web>
</system.web>
  <location path="Home">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
<system.webServer>
```

This is my web config but it still redirects me when i try to go on /home

Comment: How does your controller look like?

Comment: FYI, web.config based security is not supported in MVC.  It may work, but Microsoft does not recommend it, and actively discourages it.  See: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute above your controller action.

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
     [AllowAnonymous]
     public ActionResult Index()
     {

     }
}
```